# Using a selected layer with processing in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

How do I create a Processing script which asks the user for a layer and then conducts an operation on it?

```
import processing
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                   QgsProcessing,
                   QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                   QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                   QgsVectorLayer)

class testAlg(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    HEXES = 'HEXES'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('testalg', text)

    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Test')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'test'

     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(self.HEXES,
                                                          self.tr('Input layer'),
                                                          [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]))

        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(self.OUTPUT,
                                                        self.tr('Output'),
                                                        QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon))

    def name(self):
        return 'testalg'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Test Algorithm')

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        hex_source1 = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.HEXES, context)
        hex_source2 = QgsVectorLayer('/Users/username/temp/hexes.shp', 'hex_source2', 'ogr')

        feedback.pushConsoleInfo(str(type(hex_source1))) # Returns QgsProcessingFeatureSource
        feedback.pushConsoleInfo(str(type(hex_source2))) # Returns QgsVectorLayer

        processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator',
                   {'INPUT':hex_source1, # Dies here as it can't accept a QgsProcessingFeatureSource
                    'FIELD_NAME':'test',
                    'FIELD_TYPE':0,
                    'FIELD_LENGTH':10,
                    'FIELD_PRECISION':6,
                    'NEW_FIELD':True,
                    'FORMULA':'( "c" / sum(  "c" )) * 100',
                    'OUTPUT':'/Users/username/temp/hexes2.shp'},
                   feedback=feedback,
                   context=context)

        return {}
```

This code fails at the `processing.run` command as it can't accept a `QgsProcessingFeatureSource` (`hex_source1`) as an input (actual error is `Incorrect parameter value for INPUT`). Using `hex_source2` works fine as that returns a `QgsVectorLayer` which is apparently fine as an input.

I have also tried `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer` which also seems to give a `QgsProcessingFeatureSource` result.

Should I be converting a `QgsProcessingFeatureSource` to a `QgsVectorLayer`? If so, how? Or is there a simpler way to load a layer for processing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

In this case, because the field calculator algorithm requires a vector layer input, you'll need to declare a QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer parameter as the input for your algorithm (not a feature source).

You'll then need to change

```
 hex_source1 = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.HEXES, context)
```

To

```
 hex_source1 = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.HEXES, context)
```

This will give you a QgsVectorLayer value for hex_source1, ready for handing off to the field calculator algorithm.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Feedback gives `<class 'NoneType'>` and the `processing.run` fails due to `Incorrect parameter value for INPUT`.

Comment: Works fine for me. Thx :-)

Answer (score 1):

Keep

```
 hex_source1 = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.HEXES, context)
```

But instead of

```
'INPUT':hex_source1
```

use

```
'INPUT':hex_source1.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest())
```

(be sur to add QgsFeatureRequest in your imports)

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing, but As pointed out [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287586/how-can-i-get-the-path-for-an-input-layer-in-a-qgis-3-script) , you can simply lookup the input layer's value from `parameters`

```
hex_source1 = parameters[self.HEXES]
```

Answer (score 0):

As ndawson pointed out, the qgis:fieldcalculator algorithm needs a VectorLayer.  I have modified your code accordingly (also had to change the formulae and output path, and removed hex_source2), and it works for me in QGIS 3.4.

```
import processing
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
               QgsProcessing,
               QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
               QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
               QgsVectorLayer)

class testAlg(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
  HEXES = 'HEXES'
  OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

  def tr(self, text):
    return QCoreApplication.translate('testalg', text)

  def createInstance(self):
    return type(self)()

  def group(self):
    return self.tr('Test')

  def groupId(self):
    return 'test'

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(self.HEXES,
                                                      self.tr('Input layer'),
                                          [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]))

    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(self.OUTPUT,
                                                    self.tr('Output'),
                                          QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon))

  def name(self):
    return 'testalg'

  def displayName(self):
    return self.tr('Test Algorithm')

  def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    hex_source1 = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.HEXES, context)
    #hex_source1 = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.HEXES, context)
    #hex_source2 = QgsVectorLayer('/Users/username/temp/hexes.shp', 'hex_source2', 'ogr')

    feedback.pushConsoleInfo(str(type(hex_source1))) # Returns QgsProcessingFeatureSource
    #feedback.pushConsoleInfo(str(type(hex_source2))) # Returns QgsVectorLayer

    processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator',
               {'INPUT':hex_source1, # Dies here as it can't accept a QgsProcessingFeatureSource
                'FIELD_NAME':'test',
                'FIELD_TYPE':0,
                'FIELD_LENGTH':10,
                'FIELD_PRECISION':6,
                'NEW_FIELD':True,
                'FORMULA':'( "FID" / sum(  "FID" )) * 100',
                'OUTPUT':'/tmp/test.shp'},
               feedback=feedback,
               context=context)

    return {}
```