# How can I get the path for an input layer in a QGIS 3 script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

Writing scripts in previous versions of QGIS, I would get the layer path to pass to algorithms using `processing.getObject(layer)`. In QGIS 3, the scripting system has been rewritten, and I now define a 'source' for input layers like this:

```
SPECIES_POINTS = 'SPECIES_POINTS'      # INPUT = 'INPUT'

[...]

speciesPointSource = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.SPECIES_POINTS,
            context
        )
```

I then try to pass it to an algorithm:

```
pointsReprojected = processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {
            'INPUT': speciesPointSource,
            'TARGET_CRS': CRS,
            'OUTPUT' : speciesExtent_id
        }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
```

but when I try to run this, I get an error:

```
Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 191, in processAlgorithm
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 96, in run
return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 142, in runAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value
```

I can see that `speciesPointSource` has type `QgsFeatureSource`, so I'm not surprised this doesn't work, but I can't see any attributes that would give me the file path for the layer. I have also tried `self.SPECIES_POINTS` but then I get the error `Could not load source layer for INPUT: SPECIES_POINTS not found.` What should I be passing as `'INPUT'`?

Answer (score 9):

The input parameters can be accessed as a dictionary object, so `parameters['SPECIES_POINTS']` will give you the path to the input layer. The call to the algorithm would then be:

```
pointsReprojected = processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {
            'INPUT': parameters['SPECIES_POINTS'],
            'TARGET_CRS': CRS,
            'OUTPUT' : speciesExtent_id
        }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
```

Note that if you are only going to be passing the input object to an algorithm without doing anything with it, it's not necessary to define it as a source. The `speciesPointSource = self.parameterAsSource(...)` section is not needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. After hours of trying, I figured that must be the only way and landed here to see the confirmation.