# Getting layer from featureSource within QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis

I'm writing a QGIS processing toolbox plugin 3.14 and need to modify its features:

I am doing something like this:

```
source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, 'LAYER', context)
features = source.getFeatures()
for current, feat in enumerate(features):
  # do something to each feature
```

How do I get the layer from the source?

To make it work, I'm doing something like this:

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layer = canvas.currentLayer()
layer.startEditing()
# Then inside the loop above
  layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), 2, value)
# And then finally:
layer.commitChanges()
layer.reload()
```

All works fine but I am confused about not being able to get to the layer from the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Processing/QgsProcessingAlgorithm.html explains that `self.parameterAsSource` creates a new object.

If you are wanting to reference a layer then you probably want `self.parameterAsVectorLayer`.

See also: [Using a selected layer with processing in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280667/using-a-selected-layer-with-processing-in-qgis-3)